# transferring data between external databases

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two of Access databases [source(TBL_PAINEL)] having the same structure of main tables, but I need to transfer the data into a [target(TBL_PAINEL2)] database, but I can not please help me. Follow code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim db1 As DAO.Database
Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbname As String

Set wrk = DBEngine(0)
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set db1 = wrk.OpenDatabase("\\fswcorp\cat\dsie\soas\gocpf\UGO\5. QA\2. DB\History_CD.accdb")

dbname = "\\fswcorp\cat\dsie\soas\gocpf\UGO\5. QA\2. DB\History_CD.accdb"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_PAINEL2 (CHAVEPAINEL, NOMECLIENTE, AGENCIA, CONTA, CONTRATO, MODALIDADE, ID_SEGMENTO, ID_PRODUTO) " _
& "SELECT TBL_PAINEL .CHAVEPAINEL, TBL_PAINEL.NOMECLIENTE, TBL_PAINEL.AGENCIA, TBL_PAINEL.CONTA, TBL_PAINEL.CONTRATO, TBL_PAINEL.MODALIDADE, TBL_PAINEL.ID_SEGMENTO, TBL_PAINEL.ID_PRODUTO " _
& "FROM TBL_PAINEL " _
& "IN '" & dbname & "';"

db1.Execute (strSQL)

wrk.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set db1 = Nothing
Set wrk = Nothing
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? Error?

Comment: i could not, the mistake was: 'Invalid bracketing of name 'Y:\SOAS\GOCPF\UGO\5. QA\2. DB\History_CD.accdb'.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really need vba here, just a plain query. save the query and run from vba if you must.

if running from a 3'rd database, that is neither source or target:

```
INSERT INTO target_table IN '\\serverpath\target.accdb'
SELECT * FROM source_table IN '\\serverpath\source.accdb'
```

if running from inside source database, just omit the path, and vice-versa if you are running from inside the target database.

```
INSERT INTO target_table IN '\\serverpath\target.accdb'
SELECT * FROM source_table
```

Comment: i could not, the mistake was: 'Invalid bracketing of name 'Y:\SOAS\GOCPF\UGO\5. QA\2. DB\History_CD.accdb'.